# How to add an account to Azure Databricks workspace region?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-databricks

I spun up an instance of Azure Databricks. When I try to login, I get the following error.

> The workspace you are trying to access does not exist in this Azure region, or your account vikrambhatt1405@outlook.com does not belong to any Databricks workspace in the region. Please ask your administrator to add you as a user, or click here to logout of Azure Active Directory and login with a different user.

I already have a role assigned to me as Service Administrator, which means access to all resources.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please follow the process below to add users to the Azure Databricks workspace :

> 1.As an administrator go to the [Admin Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/admin-console).
>
> 2.On the Users tab, click Add User.
>
> 3.Provide the user email ID.
>
> You can add any user who belongs to the Azure Active Directory tenant
> of your Azure Databricks workspace.
>
> [image: Add user]
>
> 4.If [cluster access control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/access-control/cluster-acl) is enabled, the user is added without cluster creation permission.

please see:[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/users-groups/users).

---

**Update:**

According to your error message:
**The workspace you are trying to access does not exist in this Azure region, or your account vikrambhatt1405@outlook.com does not belong to any Databricks workspace in the region.**
So,I think your account does not belong In this workspace,you should try to add your account as a user following the instructions of the error message.

The instructions in the document are indeed not very clear, you can follow this process to operate, go to Azure portal>Azure Databricks:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I already saw the instructions prior to the posting. I cannot find the admin console as the instruction says "top right of workspace UI" ambiguous and unclear. On other hand, I do have permissions as service admin, which means  I am the owner.

Comment: @Thank you. The error occurs when I tried to launch the workspace from the URL it shows the above error. But I just launched it from the button Launch Workspace, and it worked. But I guess it's just one of the things in development where it just miraculously work by a mistake. I accept the answer and close the thread.

Comment: @VikramBhatt   I'm so happy for you, can you accept it as an answer?(click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in).

Comment: My company (LEGO) has tens of thousands of users. I would really like to add "All Users" as a contributor so I can link directly to notebooks from documentation/wiki pages. This doesn't seem possible. I'm looking into SCIM provisioning but it seems silly and a crazy stress test, needing to sync all users just to make an internally public Databricks workspace. Aren't there any other solutions?

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer and comments led me there, but because it is so awkward I figured it would be good to post as a separate answer:

Instead of clicking on the 'url', click the blue button called 'Launch workspace' to access the cluster.

Comment: Thank you!! I spent a long time trying to figure this out before scrolling down to see your answer.